# Can a class contain its own class?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, uml, class-design, composition

Suppose I have the following class structure:

[image]

1. A forest can have any number of trees, but each tree can belong to only one forest. If the forest is deleted, the tree is deleted.
2. A tree must have at least one branch, but can have many more, however each branch can belong to only one tree. If the tree is deleted, the branch is deleted.
3. A branch can have any number of leaves, and each leaf can belong to only one branch. If the branch is deleted, the leaf is deleted.

I believe this is a 'composition' structure, where each child depends on its parent for existence.

How might I represent a structure where **each branch can contain other branches, which can contain other branches**, and so on and so forth, essentially like this:

[image]

Notice the infinite loop I've added to branch, suggesting that a branch can contain any number of 'child' branches, which can in turn contain any number of child branches etc etc, similar to how a real tree might function, where each branch can contain smaller branches, which can in turn contain smaller branches:

[image]

How might I therefore create a structure where:

1. Each branch class can contain an infinite (and unknown) number of 'child' branch classes
2. Each branch can have access to itself and its child branches only (i.e it cannot see parent data)
3. Each branch has the ability to make decisions for itself and its child branches only (i.e. the chain of power over subordinates increases as you move up the chain towards the parent)

In other words, a simple heirarchy structure, but with a flexible hierarchy depth.

It is this **unknown** number of parent/child generations which is causing me difficulty. If I knew that a 'grandparent' branch can only contain 'parent' branches, which in turn can only contain 'child' branches, then I could easily hardcode 3 classes to represent grandparent/parent/child branches.

However since the number of 'generations' is unknown, I can't seem to get my head around how this might be represented in a UML Class Diagram, and later implemented.

How might I best approach this?

Comment: [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)

Comment: Just the way you did it; that's perfectly fine (the objection by qwerty_so is about the notational semantics of the filled diamond in UML, but that's besides the point). It's just a recursive structure; implementation wise, all you need is a member variable that stores a collection of branches (e.g. `List<Branch>`) in your `Branch` class, and possibly a mechanism to determine if the branch has child branches.

Comment: Sure, this is pretty common. For example the browser DOM is such a tree.

Comment: Have you learned about "class structures" before you have learned about data structures? What you describe is, perhaps ironically, called a *tree*.

Comment: The class per se doesn't contain anything; instances of the class can contain other instances, even of the same class. I know, it's largely just a matter of terminology, but I think using the right terminology can clear up possible misconceptions and offer a better mental model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Can a class contain its own class?

Yes. Case in point:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo Parent { get; set; }
}

var parent = new Foo();
var child = new Foo() { Parent = parent };
```

However, a class cannot then have *only* constructors which require a parameter of the same class, such as

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo Parent { get; }

    public Foo(Foo parent)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

The language allows it, but it's impossible to ever create such an object, as it leads to an infinitely recursing chain of constructors:

```
var parent = new Foo(new Foo(new Foo(new Foo(...)))); // to infinity!
```

This just never ends.

*Edit: user1937198 correctly pointed out that you can simply pass in `null` (barring some constraints such as C#'s non-nullable types), but that is in my opinion off-label usage as it's conceptually contradictory to (a) have a constructor ask for an object (b) not provide any constructor which doesn't aks for that object, and then (c) not passing an object.*

However, if there are other constructors available as well, then there is no problem. The first created object is simply limited to using the constructors without the same class as constructor parameter

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo Parent { get; }

    public Foo(Foo parent)
    {
        this.Parent = parent;
    }

    public Foo()
    {

    }
}

var parent = new Foo();
var child = new Foo(parent);
```

As a general rule, there are three ways to model this relationship:

1. Parent-oriented:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo Parent { get; set; }
}

var parent = new Foo();
var child = new Foo() { Parent = parent };
```

2. Child-oriented:

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<Foo> Children { get; set; }
}

var child = new Foo();
var parent = new Foo();
parent.Children.Add(child);
```

3. Both (this is commonly used for navigational properties such as in Entity Framework)

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo Parent { get; set; }
    public List<Foo> Children { get; set; }
}

var parent = new Foo();
var child = new Foo() { Parent = parent };
parent.Children.Add(child);
```

---

### How might I therefore create a `Branch`?

> I believe this is a 'composition' structure, where each child depends on its parent for existence.
> How might I represent a structure where each branch can contain other branches, which can contain other branches, and so on and so forth

For reference, what you're looking for here is a 'recursive' structure, as opposed to a 'composite' structure.

Note that 'recursive' doesn't inherently mean a self-relationship (i.e. `Branch->Branch->Branch->...`), it could also be a longer chain without self-relationships (e.g. `A->B->C->A->B->C->...`), though that distinction is irrelevant for your specific use case.

> 1. Each branch class can contain an infinite (and unknown) number of 'child' branch classes

This is describing a collection, e.g. `List<Branch>`. Other collection types exist but I'm using `List<>` for simplicity's sake.

> 2. Each branch can have access to itself and its child branches only (i.e it cannot see parent data)

Therefore, a branch needs to contain such a collection of (child) branches:

```
public class Branch
{
    public List<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
}
```

This is the child-oriented example from the previous examples.

> 3. Each branch has the ability to make decisions for itself and its child branches only (i.e. the chain of power over subordinates increases as you move up the chain towards the parent)

3 is a logical consequence of 2, so it is automatically achieved when 2 is achieved.

> I can't seem to get my head around how this might be represented in a UML Class Diagram

**Branch-to-branch**

Your UML is perfectly fine in regards to the self-relationship. You drew a relationship from `Branch` to `Branch`, which does express it.

This kind of relationship is inherently recursive (i.e. what you call "infinite depth"). It's actually impossible to avoid recursion here, because that would require using multiple types to denote branches that can/can't have further children.

Note that while the relationship itself is inherently recursive, it's possible that your business logic might enforce a maximum depth. Maybe not necessary for your case, but it is a general possibility.
However, that sort of depth-limit is not visible on a UML diagram, and shouldn't particularly be visible as UML diagrams do not contain validation or business logic.

**Tree-to-branch**

However, do note that the relationship a branch has with its tree has changed. The "child" branches won't be related to a tree, they'll be related to their parent branch. And the "top" branch will have the relationship to the tree.

This means that your tree-to-branch relationship is now a `0..1 to many` relationship.

---

### **Complexity vs security**

I just want to point out that there are circumstances which can change the outcome.

If **only** a branch which has no child branches is allowed to have leaves, and branches with child branches are not allowed to, your UML is flawed, as *all* branches can have leaves.
If this is what you need, then you're going to need to model different types for a "branch-having branch" and a "leaf-having branch".

*Note: I'm aware that in your drawing of a tree you drew leaves on all kinds of branches, but I also suspect that your tree scenario is an example and not indicative of what you may be trying to build in reality.*

Similarly, your UML is relying on your business logic ensuring that only the ancestor branch is connected to the tree, not any other branch. If you wish to model this more securely, then you would also need to distinguish between a "tree-related branch" and a "branch-related branch".

However, there is some degree of freedom here. You *could* model that in your UML, but it will complicate the diagram. You could also stick to simple modeling with only a `Branch` type which could all be related to a tree, child branches, and leaves; and then rely on your business logic to ensure that you build your graph the right way.

This very much depends on whether you're willing to take on the added model complexity in order to outright prevent "bad" graphs, which requires context from how bad an error in your application is.

- For example, if it could kill people by malfunctioning, prioritize security (enforcing it through the diagram) over simplicity (relying on business logic).
- On the other hand, if this is a simple app that e.g. tracks cooking recipes, at the very worst you're going to get some dirty data that needs cleaning, which is a negligible issue and is not worth the headaches that such a complex UML diagram would cause.

Comment: This is great. So if I understand your child-orientated structure correctly: 1) a branch object will store a list of optional 'child' branch objects which are its dependents, 2) dependent branches can be accessed by recursively iterating through child lists, and 3) since each branch object may or may not be directly attached to the tree, the tree-to-branch relationship must change to `0..1 to many`. However doesn't `0..1 to many` this mean that its now perfectly possible for a tree to have no branches? Am I still able to enforce that a tree must contain at least one branch?

Comment: @Alan: Your UML can specify a `0..1 to 1..many` relationship, but in code it's not possible to do so through class design alone (that I am aware of). Collections are inherently `0..*`. Requiring a tree to have at least one branch in its collection of branches is validation logic on that collection, which is the avenue you should explore to enforce this rule; but this kind of validation is separate from the class design itself. Before then, you can write it on the human-readable UML, but not enshrine it in the class structure which is based on your UML.

Comment: I have just briefly looked up 'recursive data structures' and it sounds like this is exactly what I need. Good point you make about potentially adding a maximum depth limit on the branch-to-branch relationship, however from what you're saying the number of loops (e.g. max 10) is not usually required to be noted on a UML class diagram?

Comment: @Alan: At the end of the day, UML is a human-readable chart. This chart is not consumed by an algorithm, so you don't need to confirm to pedantic preset rules. As long as it remains human-readable and the readers value the information, it's a good diagram. You're always able to add the comment if you truly feel it adds value to the reader, but it's not "prescribed" UML usage. Similarly, I tend to never distinguish `0..*` vs `1..*` relationships, I just use `*` because that's how the class will be designed anyway. That's my opinion, and you may disagree and find this an important distinction.

Comment: @Alan: Just for completeness, the only relationships I tend to model are `1` (required), `0..1` (optional) and `*` (many). So far, I have not had any complaints about the diagram being unclear or unreadable. You could add the "at least one" constraint to the diagram, but that's in my opinion business logic, and the rest of the business logic doesn't belong on a UML chart, so why would this specific bit of logic be relevant? Again, this is just my opinion, I like to keep a clean separation between class design and business logic because not all business logic fits in a class design diagram.

Comment: This is very helpful. Excuse my questions, I'm very new to UML, trying to use them to better document class structures, processes etc. Just wanted to better understand what is considered 'useful' information in a diagram vs technically misleading - I noticed someone earlier commented about one of the arrows being incorrect so I wasn't sure how accurate these diagrams need to be to achieve their purpose. I agree it comes down to usability and function, and additional details and nuances can always be noted. Thanks for your detailed explainations, some very good considerations :)

Comment: @Alan: My advice may offend some UML purists because I don't use strict UML, but I tend to favor practicality over preaching dogma.  I'm not a stickler for diagrams, I use them as they suit me, commonly as a "zoomed out" visualization of a group of classes (which an IDE is not great at visualizing). To be honest, I can never tell the difference between the arrow types, and it's not something I've needed to know to do my job. I didn't even need the arrows on your lines to understand your diagram and intention.

Comment: At least in Java, there is a fairly simple way to construct the class which requires itself in the constructor: `null`. To take your example class, `new Foo(null)` is a perfectly valid way of creating the final Foo.

Comment: No, UML is not just a 'human readable chart'. (I've twenty plus years experience in generating executable code from UML and similar models, CASE tools doing model checking and design proving). UML is a model that may be communicated via diagrams, but the difference between UML and a sketch on a whiteboard is that you can process the model with a machine. There's almost no point in using something as complicated as UML if you're only drawing a picture for a human.

Comment: @user1937198: I am astounded how I totally missed the `null` value approach... Genuinely. However, I do consider that off-label usage as it circumvents the whole concept of both (1) asking for an object in the constructor and (2) very specifically not creating constructors that _don't_ ask for this object. That's not a guarantee, but it does sound more like a workaround than an intended usage.

Comment: @PeteKirkham There is a _vast_ part of the sector that uses a UML-like approach to simply communicate to others (or whiteboard for themselves) a general entity diagram and class design, without any expectation of it being consumed by an actual algorithm. Not once in my decade long interaction as a consultant have I come across a client that uses UML diagrams in any way other than as a communication/whiteboarding tool. I agree that when an algorithm processes it, pedantical consistency is very much needed for a good working, but that is not the sole way in which UML is being used.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the already given suggestion to use the composite pattern, I see two ways to fix this model:

1. Replace the `1:*` relationships between "trees -> branches" and "branches -> branches" by a `{0,1}:*` aggregation. Add a constraint to the model enforcing that exactly one of the two parent-child references must be valid for each branch object.
2. Keep the `1:*` aggregation between "trees -> branches", but make the relationship for "branches -> branches" a `{0,1}:*` *association*. Here, the tree is the "owner" of all of its branches, if regardless if they are directly "starting" at the tree or somewhere in the middle.

The first approach has the advantage that it will make easier to take out a branch with sub-branches from the first tree and move it to anothe tree. But it may be more effort to run an algorithm which does something "for all branches", this will always require a recursive scan.

Finally, you wrote

> Notice the infinite loop I've added to branch

You didn't. You added a loop. The loop only becomes "infinite" if someone interconnects the objects in a cyclic way.

> I can't seem to get my head around how this might be later implemented.

Here is a very simplistic implementation in C#. It might not be sufficient for a real application, but I guess you get the idea:

```
// Variant 1
class Branch
{
    public Tree MyTree{get; private set;}

    public Branch ParentBranch{get; private set;}

    public Branch(Tree tree){MyTree = tree;}
    public Branch(Branch parentBranch)
    {
        // MyTree stays null here
        ParentBranch = parentBranch;
    }

    public Branch AddNewBranch(){return new Branch(this);}
    // the "Tree" class will contain a similar method
}
```

```
// Variant 2
class Branch
{
    public Tree MyTree{get; private set;}

    public Branch ParentBranch{get; private set;}

    public Branch(Tree tree){MyTree = tree;}

    public Branch(Branch parentBranch)
    {
         MyTree = parentBranch.MyTree;
         ParentBranch= parentBranch;
    }
    public Branch AddNewBranch(){return new Branch(this);}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the UML, but here is a C++ implementation which compiles and runs. This solution uses abstract base classes. So a Branch contains "children" each of which can be either a Leaf or a another Branch.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;

 // Base class for formatted output of structure
class WoodBase {
public:
    virtual ~WoodBase() {
    }

    virtual const char *getType() = 0;

    virtual void outputChildren(int depth) {}

    void output(int depth = 0) {
        int tabs = depth;
        while (tabs--) cout << '\t';
        cout << getType() << '\n';
        outputChildren(depth + 1);

    }
};

// Base class for container classes
template<class T> class WoodParent : public WoodBase {
protected:
    std::vector<T *> _children;

    template<class CHILD> CHILD *addChild() {
        CHILD *child = new CHILD();
        _children.push_back(child);
        return child;
    }

public:
    virtual ~WoodParent() {
        for (auto i: _children) delete i;
    }

    virtual void outputChildren(int depth) {
        for (auto i: _children) i->output(depth);
    }
};

class Leaf : public WoodBase {
public:
    const char *getType() { return "Leaf"; }
};

class Branch : public WoodParent<WoodBase> {
public:
    const char *getType() { return "Branch"; }

    Branch *addBranch() { return addChild<Branch>(); }

    Leaf *addLeaf() { return addChild<Leaf>(); }
};

class Tree : public WoodParent<Branch> {
public:
    const char *getType() { return "Tree"; }

    Branch *addBranch() { return addChild<Branch>(); }
};

class Forest : public WoodParent<Tree> {
public:
    const char *getType() { return "Forest"; }

    Tree *addTree() { return addChild<Tree>(); }
};

int main() {
    Forest forest;

    // Create trees, branches and leaves
    Tree *tree1 = forest.addTree();
    Branch *branch = tree1->addBranch();
    branch->addLeaf();
    branch->addLeaf();
    tree1->addBranch()->addBranch()->addLeaf();

    //Another tree with many sub branches
    forest.addTree()->addBranch()->addBranch()->addBranch()->addBranch()->addLeaf();

    forest.output();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Forest
    Tree
        Branch
            Leaf
            Leaf
        Branch
            Branch
                Leaf
    Tree
        Branch
            Branch
                Branch
                    Branch
                        Leaf
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can, a class can contain objects of it's own class;

So what you want to do is create a branch class that contains details of all it's children, the implementation of what you've described could be like this:

```
class Branch
{
    private String name;
    private List<Branch> childBranches; //only tracking child branches of current branch

    public Branch(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addChild(Branch branchToBeAdded)
    {
        childBranches.add(branchToBeAdded);
    }

}
```

So now each branch can contain infinite number of child branches.

Comment: In particular, `childBranches` will often be empty.